# django testing views with login_required decorator respecting DRY

Tags: django, testing, login-required

I have a website where all views will be protected with @login_required, except for the login view, of course.
However, using the decorator will cause my tests calling these views to fail if I do not add an authentificated user to the request. I know that this can be done in setUp() but writing the same line in any test class is not respecting DRY principle.

Is there a better approach than this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say, you can move the login to the `setUp` method to avoid duplication in every test in the test class.

If you do not like duplicating the `setUp` method in every test class, you could create your own test case class or mixin.

```
class LoggedInTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user(username='username', password='password')
        self.client.login(username='username', password='password')

class MyTestCase(LoggedInTestCase):
    def test_stuff(self):
        ...
```

If you override the `setUp` method in your child class, remember to call `super()`.

```
class MyOtherTestCase(LoggedInTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(MyOtherTestCase, self).setUp()
        # other setUp code goes here

    def test_other_stuff(self):
        ...
```

Comment: how could I possibly miss that... Thanks for opening my eyes again.